# Delete n characters from string ending to make it a string with exact length

Tags: ruby

How can i elegantly delete all the characters from the end of the string to make it match the exact length.

For example i have a string `1234567...`. I need a string with length 6, so i need to delete `7...`. Note `7...` may contain any amount of symbols.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can index a string with a range:

```
s = "12345678"
s[0...6] # => "123456"
```

Answer (score 2):

```
string = "abcdefghigkl"
# get first 7 chars without affecting on original string
new_string = string[0,6]
# force remove from 7th char
string[6..-1] = ""
string
#=> "abcdef"
```